# I would like a matplotlib graph created in python to open via button on my pqt main window

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer

I have created a graph in python using pandas to extract the data and matplotlib to create a graph. I have then created a main window with one button in qt designer and created a py file copy so I can add a function to the button to open the graph from the python application. Is there a way to actual do this? I have used

```
subprocess.call(['pythonw', baebropgh.py])
```

but this opens the main window which is good but when I click the button a terminal opens and just says RESTART: shell
below is the code from the pyqt:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import subprocess

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    #push button graph
    self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 240, 111, 21))
    self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
    #push button action
    self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.open_file)

MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
    self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
    self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
    MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
    self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
    MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
    self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Graph"))

def open_file(self):
    subprocess.call(['pythonw', baebrogph.py])

if __name__ == "__main__":
import sys
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
MainWindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around. I just save the plot graph as a png using

```
plt.savefig('foo.png')
```

then got the button in my pyqt to open the png file.